# How to destroy the screen with blessed and nodejs

Tags: node.js, npm

I am using nodejs and blessed for creating a small form asking for YES or NO. Once the input is accepted, I want to destroy the whole screen and do a callback. When I use screen.destroy, the terminal just shows blank screen and no callback initiated. All the examples shows to handle the keys on keypress and do process.exit(0). But my code still has some job left after the user's input. How to handle this?

```
    exports.acceptYorN = function (filecontent, cb) {
        var form = blessed.form({….});

        form.on(‘submit’, function(){
            cb(‘Y’);
            screen.destroy();
        }

        //similar for cancel as well
    }

    In a different file, nodejs function
    function parent() {
        acceptYorN(‘mycontent’, function(msg) {
            console.log(msg);
            if (msg ===‘Y’) {
                //do something
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: The nodejs calling the blessed module just stuck after screen.destroy() call. I have to manually kill the process.

Comment: Is there any code that you can post to help us find your problem?

Comment: Here is the one I am using https://github.com/chjj/blessed/blob/master/example/simple-form.js. In the form.on for submit or cancel, I have a to do a callback and destroy the screen. No escape sequences are accepted.